# Como passar uma lista de um objeto que contém outro objeto (composição) pra um JSON

Tags: java, web-service, rest, vraptor

Tenho duas classes: Contato e Operadora. A na classe Contato tenho uma composição: `private Operadora operadora`; Tenho um DAO aonde tenho uma classe que retorna uma lista de Contatos, no console a lista é exibida dessa forma:

```
[Contato [nome=Diego Augusto, telefone=3525-4566, data=Mon Sep 14 13:43:42 BRT 2015, operadora=Operadora [nome=Tim, codigo=41, categoria=Celular, valor=2]]]
```

Porém quando tento passar essa consulta pro método que serializa o JSON o resultado é esse:

```
{
nome: "Diego Augusto"
telefone: "3525-4566"
data: "2015-09-14T13:50:16-0300"
}
```

Como podem ver a operadora não é exibida, como posso exibir a operadora no JSON?

Meu controller:

```
@Controller
@Path("/contato")
public class ContatoController {
    @Inject
    private Result result;
    @Inject
    private ContatoDAO contatoDAO;

    @Get
    @Path("/contatos")
    public void listAll() {
        System.out.println("TESTE: "+contatoDAO.lista());
        result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(contatoDAO.lista()).serialize();
    }

}
```

DAO :

```
//Testando...
public List<Contato>lista(){
        List<Contato>listaContatos = new ArrayList<>();
        Contato c = new Contato();
        Operadora o = new Operadora();

        c.setNome("Diego Augusto");
        c.setData(new Date());
        c.setTelefone("3525-4566");

        o.setCodigo(41);
        o.setNome("Tim");
        o.setCategoria("Celular");
        o.setValor(new BigDecimal(2));
        c.setOperadora(o);

        listaContatos.add(c);


        return listaContatos;
    }
```

Comment: A sua classe `Contato` tem um getter público pra sua referência a `Operadora`?

Comment: Tem sim @TúlioF.

Comment: Tenta limpar o cache do seu navegador `Ctrl-F5`, as vezes tu muda o código mas teu browser tá devolvendo a página à partir do cache.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas achei a solução pro problema rs

Comment: Então por favor responda sua própria pergunta, isso pode ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. Você pode aceitar a sua própria resposta como correta.

Comment: Sim, já estava respondendo! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando um `include("operadora")` no `result` dessa forma:

```
result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(contatoDAO.lista()).include("operadora").serialize();
```